# Ask for a solution to an ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume $y=y(x)$. There is an ODE problem:

$(\cos x)y'(2+\sin^2x(y')^2)+(\sin x)y''=0$

It is obvious that $y'=0$ is a solution, but this is what I guess and I have no idea how to solve it systematically, so I ask for your solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

Since $y$ doesn't appear explicitly in the equation, you could set $z=y'$ and then of course $z'=y''$. Plugging this into the ODE will give you a *first order* ODE for $z(x)$.

Being more specific:

The substitution gives $$z \cos x(2+\sin^2x z^2)+(\sin x)z'=0 $$ multiply both sides by $z$ $$ \cos x (2z^2+\sin^2x (z^2)^2)+ \frac{1}{2} \sin x (z^2)'=0$$ now set $w=z^2$, this gives you a Bernoulli equation for $w$: $$(\frac{1}{2} \sin x)w'+2w \cos x+ w^2 \cos x \sin^2 x=0 $$ 
You can solve this to get $$w=\frac{1}{c \sin^4x-\cos^2 x \sin^2x }$$ Getting $z$ back from $w$ is a piece of cake, and an additional integration gives $y$.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems not easy to proceed with the first order ODE...

Comment: I've editen my answer. Please review it once more

Comment: Brilliant! I got it. Thank you very much!